# How do we display hours completed in current sprint in a query

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, agile, sprint

I have a query that I am surprised has not been asked before (or maybe my search skills are not that great)

We are following `Scrum` and use `Azure devops` to track it, in that the lowest grain is a task, that has `Original Estimate`, `Completed Work` and `Remaining Work`

If for some reason a task is started in a sprint and is not finished, there are Some Completed Hours and some Remaining Hours left on the task.

We want to create a query that shows us no. of hours worked on a task in current (given) sprint

so for example -

End of Sprint 1

```
Task 1 -
Original Estimate = 20 hrs
Completed hours = 12 hours
Remaining hours = 8 hours

Task 2 -
Original Estimate = 10 hrs
Completed hours = 5 hours
Remaining hours = 8 hours
```

End of Sprint 2

```
Task 1 -
Original Estimate = 20 hrs
Completed hours = 20 hours
Remaining hours = 0 hours
Status - done

Task 2 -
Original Estimate = 10 hrs
Completed hours = 13 hours
Remaining hours = 3 hours
Status - In progress
```

Now I want to see, how much effort was made in Sprint 2 for each task-
Hence for

Task 1

```
8hrs - Planned
8hrs - completed
0 hrs - remaining
```

Task 2

```
8hrs - Planned
8hrs - completed
3 hrs - remaining
```

Hope it makes sense, please let me know if I could explain it any better.

Comment: I very good question and well asked. Im scouring the web for the answer and cant find it so far. Devops has every conceivable feature except the most basic and first question management will ask "How many hours did the each developer spend this week"

Answer (score 0):

afaik you cannot create such a query which would capture history diff.

i see other options in how you could achieve this:

1. create a simple query which would get completed, estimated and planned hours for a task for current iteration
2. run the query on each sprint-end end and export the data
3. use other tools to calculate the diff, based on Task Id, e.g. Excel or PowerBi